# Cloud services for image search by metadata tags

Tags: images, cloud-service, search, metadata, tags

I'd appreciate any recommendations with regards to such online services for image search.

My special focus relates to services that support

1. sharing with other pre-approved registered users,
2. imposing restrictions that would limit the option to download images (one can only search by metadata, but not to save)
3. searching by hierarchical meta-tags.

- so I'd kindly ask you to provide along with your recommendation also some comments on 1), 2) and 3).

Thanks in advance.